# c# error AssemblyResolve resources dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013

My scenario is: an .exe that use some dll's created by me.

Recently I have migrated from visual studio 2008 *(with framework 2.0)* to visual studio 2013 *(with framework 4.0)*

everything is ok, but now happens this thing: in my Program.cs i've this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}

static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dll not registered in GAC or wrong version:\r\n" + args.Name, "ERROR DLL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return null;
}
```

and now retrieve this error:

```
SeaUser.resources, Version=3.0.5550.25069, Culture=it-IT, PublicKeyToken=null
```

this seems that the SeaUser.dll is not compiled with all the resources?

the strange thing is that if I can't check this, everything works, and the resources of the dll *(images of some buttons)* are all shown correctly.

so, what's the problem? with vs2013 or framework 4.0 this function doesn't work like the old *(I does'n thave the dlls in the gac but in the .exe folder)*

thanks!

Comment: did you try to remove and add your references back to your project ? i would try re-compiling the DLLs with VS2013 and see if it clean things up

Comment: yes @Shide, it was the first thing I did

Comment: It is probing for a satellite assembly for some mysterious reason.  We can't guess why when you don't show us a stack trace.  It is otherwise benign, failure to locate a satellite assembly is not an error and since you are Italian it should just fallback to the default localization which is no doubt Italian as well.  Don't complain when the culture of the assembly isn't neutral.